# Anonymous methods - variable capture versus value capture

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Below is a SSCCE based on an example in the Anonymous Methods section of Part 1
of Chris Rolliston's excellent Delphi XE2 Foundations book, about the idea of variable
capture (any errors in it are entirely down to me).

It works exactly as I'd expect, logging 666, 667, 668, 669 on successive clicks of the
BtnInvoke button.  In particular it nicely illustrates how the captured version of the
local variable I persists long after btnSetUpClick exits.

So far so good.  The problem I'm asking about isn't with this code per se but with
what's said in Allen Bauer's blog here:

http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/10/15/38876

Now, I know better than to argue with the boss, so I am sure I'm missing the point
of the distinction he draws between variable capture and value capture.  To my simple way
of looking at it, my CR-based example captures the value of I by capturing I as a variable.

So, my question is, what is the distinction Mr Bauer is trying to draw, exactly?

(Btw, despite watching the Delphi section of SO daily for 9+ months, I'm still not entirely
clear if this q is on-topic.  If not, my apologies and I'll take it down.)

```
type
  TAnonProc = reference to procedure;

var
  P1,
  P2 : TAnonProc;

procedure TForm2.Log(Msg : String);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Msg);
end;

procedure TForm2.btnSetUpClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  I : Integer;
begin
  I := 41;
  P1 := procedure
    begin
      Inc(I);
      Log(IntToStr(I));
    end;

  I := 665;
  P2 := procedure
    begin
      Inc(I);
      Log(IntToStr(I));
    end;
end;

procedure TForm2.btnInvokeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Assert(Assigned(P1));
  Assert(Assigned(P2));

  P1;
  P2;
end;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Variable capture vs value capture is simple enough. Let us suppose that two anonymous methods capture the same variable. Like this:

```
Type
  TMyProc = reference to procedure;
var
  i: Integer;
  P1, P2: TMyProc;
....
i := 0;
P1 := procedure begin Writeln(i); inc(i); end;
P2 := procedure begin Writeln(i); inc(i); end;
P1();
P2();
Writeln(i);
```

There is a single variable that is captured by both methods. The output is:

```
0
1
2
```

This is capture of a variable. If the value was captured, which it isn't, one might imagine that the two methods would have separate variables that both started with value 0. And both functions might output 0.

In your example, you are supposed to imagine that `P1` captures the value `41`, and `P2` captures the value `665`. But that does not happen. There is exactly one variable. It is shared between the procedure that declares it, and the anonymous methods that capture it. It lives as long as all parties that share it live. Modifications to the variable made by one party are seen by all others because there is exactly one variable.

---

So, it is not possible to capture a value. To get behaviour that feels like that you need to copy a value to a new variable, and capture that new variable. That can be done with, for instance, a parameter.

```
function CaptureCopy(Value: Integer): TMyProc;
begin
  Result := procedure begin Writeln(Value); end;
end;

...
P3 := CaptureCopy(i);
```

This will copy the value of `i` into a new variable, the procedure parameter, and capture that. Subsequent changes to `i` have no influence on `P3` because the captured variable is local to `P3`.

Comment: I added a value capture example as well. I think that a good programming style would be to always be explicit about how to reference variables. Many times you get away with a reference capture (when you actually want a value capture) if the value is left unchanged later in the scope, but therein lies a potential risk if you later add something to the code which changes the value.

Comment: @LURD Capture is always of a variable, and never of a value. Your example captures a variable, because of course that is all that can be done. There is no value capture. What happens is that the value is copied to a new variable when you call `CaptureValue`. I think you should perhaps explain that as well.

Comment: @LURD I made a further edit. I hope that's alright. Thanks for the input.

Comment: i got `[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(54): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'TMyProc'`,how can i fix this?

Answer (score 8):

Let us clarify the things a bit; internally any data captured by an anonymous method is a field of a hidden object instance and should be called *variable* as such; but there can be different cases of capturing a variable.

Consider the sample code:

```
type
  TMyProc = reference to procedure;

function CaptureValue(Value: Integer): TMyProc;
begin
  Result := procedure begin Inc(Value); Writeln(Value); end;
end;

procedure Test1;
var
  Proc1: TMyProc;
  I: Integer;

begin
  I:= 32;
  Proc1:= CaptureValue(I);
  Proc1();
  Writeln(I);     // 32
end;

procedure Test2;
var
  Proc2: TMyProc;
  I: Integer;

begin
  I:= 32;
  Proc2:= procedure begin Inc(I); Writeln(I); end;
  Proc2();
  Writeln(I);    // 33
end;
```

You can see that logically the `Proc1` (in `Test1`) captures a *value* of `I`  while the `Proc2` (in `Test2`) captures a *reference* to `I`.

If you look under the hood you'll notice that the variable `I` in `Test1` is a plain local stack-based variable while `Proc1` accesses a field of a hidden object instance (using reference to the instance and offset of the field); we have 2 different variables (one on stack and the other on heap).

`Test2` has no stack-based `I` variable at all, only a field of a hidden object instance; both `Test2` and `Proc2` access the same variable by reference to the instance (and the field's offset); we have a single heap variable.

Comment: +1.  Pity one can only accept one answer.  For me, the penny dropped as soon as I read the first version of David's answer.