# Dynamically assigning anonymous functions in pascal

Tags: delphi, anonymous-function, delphi-xe6

I would like to be able to dynamically generate popup menus in pascal.

I would also like to be able to dynamically assign OnClick handlers to each menu item.

This is the sort of thing that I am used to being able to do in C#, this is my attempt in pascal.

The menu item onClick event handler needs to belong to an object (`of Object`) so I create a container object for this.

Here is my code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Menus;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TFoo = class
    public
      Bar : String;
      Val : Integer;
  end;

  TNotifyEventWrapper = class
    private
      FProc: TProc<TObject>;
      I : Integer;
    public
      constructor Create(Proc: TProc<TObject>);
    published
      procedure Event(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  NE : TNotifyEventWrapper;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TNotifyEventWrapper.Create(Proc: TProc<TObject>);
begin
    inherited Create;
    FProc := Proc;
end;

procedure TNotifyEventWrapper.Event(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(I));
    FProc(Sender);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
    F : TFoo;
    I: Integer;
    mi : TMenuItem;
begin
    if Assigned(NE) then FreeAndNil(NE);

    for I := 1 to 10 do
    begin
        F := TFoo.Create;
        F.Bar := 'Hello World!';
        F.Val := I;
        NE := TNotifyEventWrapper.Create
        (
            procedure (Sender :TObject)
            begin
               ShowMessage(F.Bar + ' ' + inttostr(F.Val) + Format('  Addr = %p', [Pointer(F)]) + Format('Sender = %p, MI.OnClick = %p', [Pointer(Sender), Pointer(@TMenuItem(Sender).OnClick)]));
            end
        );
        NE.I := I;

        mi := TMenuItem.Create(PopupMenu1);

        mi.OnClick := NE.Event;

        mi.Caption := inttostr(F.Val);

        PopupMenu1.Items.Add(mi);
    end;
end;

end.
```

[image: MenuItems]

On clicking menu item number 6

The program shows the expected message

[image: Menu6]

However the next message was not showing the expected result.

Instead of 6 it shows item 10

[image: Menu10]

No matter which item in the list I click on, they all seem to fire the event handler for the last item in the list (10).

It has been suggested to me that the `NE` object's member procedure `Event` is the same memory address for all instances of that object.

Whichever menu item I click on, the memory address `MI.OnClick` is the same.

Comment: I'm wondering whether I have found a bug/limitation of delphi

Comment: No you have not. You just haven't fully understood a nuance of variable capture yet. It captures variables rather than values.

Comment: Note that your code leaks. I assume you know this and have a plan to tackle that later.

Comment: The code address of the OnClick event is always the same. It's the address of TNotifyEventWrapper.Event. The handler's data address varies though.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yea I know this leaks, its actually a small dummy example I created when trying to do this in a larger program. I've incorporated your solution into my program now. I use FastMM4 to spot leaks and so far it hasn't complained.

Comment: Apart from variable capturing problem - do you know that dedicated object is not needed here for event handling? (You can assign form methods as handlers like FormCreate)

Comment: @MBo By dedicated Object did you mean the TNotifyEventWrapper ?

Comment: @MBo OnClick needs to be `of Object` unfortunately, although I would like to do this without it.

Comment: @MBo But sav wants to associate different data to each item's handler.

Comment: @sav It's all OK, your FormCreate? for example, is `of object` type (method)

Comment: @David Heffernan I see that author uses C# patterns like delegates instead of Delphi way. Associated data might be linked through object (menuitem) itself. Probably, it is a question for further discussion.

Comment: @MBo Well anon methods are core Delphi now. They are perhaps not a great fit here though. However, using TComponent, with its lifetime management should do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key to understanding this is to understand that variable capture captures **variables** rather than **values**.

Your anon methods all capture the same variable `F`. There's only one instance of that variable since `FormCreate` only executes once. That explains the behaviour. When your anon methods execute the variable `F` has the value assigned to it in the final loop iteration.

What you need is for each different anon method to capture a different variable. You can do this by making a new stack frame when generating each different anon method.

```
function GetWrapper(F: Foo): TNotifyEventWrapper;
begin
  Result := TNotifyEventWrapper.Create(
    procedure(Sender: TObject)
    begin
      ShowMessage(F.Bar + ...);
    end
  );
end;
```

Because the argument to the function `GetWrapper` is a local variable in that function's stack frame, each invocation of `GetWrapper` creates a new instance of that local variable.

You can place `GetWrapper` where you please. As a nested function in `FormCreate`, or as a private method, or at unit scope.

Then build your menus like this:

```
F := TFoo.Create;
F.Bar := 'Hello World!';
F.Val := I;
NE := GetWrapper(F);
NE.I := I;
```

*Related reading:*

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi#Variable_Binding_Mechanism
- [Anonymous methods - variable capture versus value capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223428/anonymous-methods-variable-capture-versus-value-capture)
- http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/10/15/38876

Comment: Since I put the constructor `F:= TFoo.Create` in a loop, I would have expected there to be 10 instances of TFoo. What have I missed

Comment: There are 10 instances of `TFoo` objects but only one instance of the variable `F`. Remember that `F` is simply a pointer. Your anon methods capture the variable. When the anon methods execute then `F` points to the last created `TFoo`.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. It using the same object reference on the stack.

Comment: Pretty much. Except that when a variable is captured the compiler "lifts" it from the stack and stores it on the heap. It has to because it can outlive the stack frame. And it does in your code. `F` lives beyond the end of `FormCreate`. That's implementation detail that you don't need to know though. It can help understanding but you don't need to know how it is implemented.