# Handling of local variable in anonymous procedure passed to TThread.Queue

Tags: multithreading, pascal, delphi

I have a program which uses a Thread that performs some work. The thread should notify another thread (in this example the main thread) of the progress.

If I use *Synchronize*() to perform the synchronization everything works as expected. If I synchronize with the main thread and publish the for-variable and put it into a list every single value get's printed correctly into my ListBox:

```
procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  inherited;

  for i := 1 to 1000 do
  begin
    Synchronize(
      procedure()
      begin
        FireEvent(i);
      end);
  end;
end;
```

> Output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 1000

If I use *Queue*() to perform the synchronization the output is not as expected:

```
procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  inherited;

  for i := 1 to 1000 do
  begin
    Queue(
      procedure()
      begin
        FireEvent(i);
      end);
  end;
end;
```

> Output: 200, 339, 562, 934, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, [...]

What's happening here? As of my understanding the anonymous procedure should capture the variable "i"?

Comment: PS: I know it doesn't makes much sense to update the UI this frequently. I just want to know what makes the variable content to change altough the anonymouse method should capture the value.

Comment: You do capture the variable. But you are trying to capture the "value". So you need to make a new variable, one for each iteration of the loop, and capture that. That requires a new stack frame, and hence a function call. Which leads to the code in LURD's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anonymous procedure captures the variable reference.
This means that the value is undetermined when the anonymous procedure runs.

In order to capture a value, you will have to wrap it into a unique frame like this:

```
Type
  TWorkerThread = class (TThread)
    ...
    function GetEventProc(ix : Integer): TThreadProcedure;
  end;

function TWorkerThread.GetEventProc(ix : Integer) : TThreadProcedure;
// Each time this function is called, a new frame capturing ix 
// (and its current value) will be produced.
begin
  Result := procedure begin FireEvent(ix); end;
end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  inherited;

  for i := 1 to 1000 do
  begin
    Queue( GetEventProc(i));
  end;
end;
```

See also [Anonymous methods - variable capture versus value capture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24223428/576719).

Comment: Should be `Queue(EventWithValue(i))` and `EventWithValue` should return a `TThreadProcedure`.  At least, that's what I would do.

Comment: Read the documentation: [Anonymous Methods in Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi), in particular [Anonymous Methods Variable Binding](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi#Anonymous_Methods_Variable_Binding).