# Anonymous Thread procedure using var parameter

Tags: multithreading, delphi, parameter-passing

This is not the first time I face an issue similar to this one : how can I get a var parameter returning values from whithin a AnonymousThread (or a TTask) ?

I need to run a procedure that takes time and consume high CPU, along the running it will populate a record with LOG information of processing that will be used later in another modules. Once there were other process to run at the same time, I put this procedure in an AnoynymousThread. Unfortunately, when it finished, I could not use the record data of LOG because it was empty.

What should I do to get this record been populated during processing inside the Thread ?

See my code :  **[UNIT ]**

```
unit UntStringThread;

interface    
uses
   System.Classes,
   System.SysUtils,
   System.Threading;

   TYPE
    TRCLog = record
       logprocess : Tstringlist;
       logrecord  : Array of Tstringlist;
    end;    

    Procedure DoBigProcess (var pRecLog : TRClog; piterations : integer);
    Procedure MajorProcessing (var pmainLog : TRCLog);

implementation 

   Procedure DoBigProcess (var pRecLog : TRClog; piterations : integer);
   Var
       localLog                 : TRCLog;
       lrows,lrecs, ltotalrecs  : integer;
       strlogrecords            : string;

   begin
        //Define pRecLog.logrecord array size
        setlength(precLog.logrecord, piterations);

        // Starts the piterations of the main process which will generates a LOG
        for lrows := 1 to piterations do
        begin
              // ... here goes critial processing that generates

              // Generate Log for the current iteration
              pRecLog.logprocess.Add('Iteration : ' + lrows.Tostring + ' ... log data about current iteration ...');

              // ... other processing goes here. Suppose total records is 10
              ltotalrecs := 10;


              // Generate Log for each record
              pRecLog.logrecord[lrows-1] := Tstringlist.Create;
              for lrecs := 1 to ltotalrecs do
              begin
                     //  some additionl processing here that generates detail log of records being processed
                     strlogrecords := '    Record : ' + lrecs.tostring + '... log data about current record being processed';
                     pRecLog.logrecord[lrows-1].Add(strlogrecords);
              end;
              pRecLog.logrecord[lrows-1].Add(' ');
         end;
   end;


   Procedure MajorProcessing (var pmainLog : TRCLog);
   var
       llog       : TRClog;
       litems     : integer;

   begin
        // some initialization processing here
        // ...
        litems := 10;

        // Runs BigProcess in an Anonymous  Thread
        llog := pmainlog;
        TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
                                      begin
                                            DoBigProcess (lLog, litems);
                                      end).Start;

        // Continuing process other stuff here

   end;
end.
```

**Main Program**

```
program ProjThreadParameter;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  UntStringThread in 'UntStringThread.pas';
var
     idxlog, idxrecord: integer;
     logmain : TRClog;
begin
  try
      logmain.logprocess := Tstringlist.Create;
      MajorProcessing (logmain);

      {==> This call, without Thread, works fine}
      //DoBigProcess(logmain,10);

      for idxlog :=0  to logmain.logprocess.Count-1 do
      begin
           Writeln(logmain.logprocess[idxlog]);
           for idxrecord :=0 to logmain.logrecord[idxlog].count-1 do
               Writeln(logmain.logrecord[idxlog][idxrecord])
      end;
      Readln;

      // PROBLEM ==> when using Thread logmain record returned empty !!

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

I had studied a previous question I've made some years ago, but I could not make it work this time. 
[iTask - values parameters to anonymous procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292602/itask-values-parameters-to-anonymous-procedure])

Appreciatte your help!

Comment: Where do you wait for the thread to complete?

Comment: I don't see where you start the anonymous thread.

Comment: What I mean is an anonymous thread is started with `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure begin DoSomething; end).Start;` or `mT := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure begin DoSomething; end); mT.Start;` Since you don't take a reference to the anonymous thread, and don't add the `Start` command, your thread is not started.

Comment: @LU RD, you are right !  I forgot this call .  I fixed the code now and updated it in here. Problem remained the same!

Comment: @David, good point!  In this sample code it is not clear, but in my original program  after calling MajorProcessing(logmain), there are several other routines that running while MajorProcessing is executing and I'll just use the results of parameter logmain  at the end of all routines. Should I force a wait for the thread finished ?  Is it mandatory ?  I did similar example using iTask and used Waitforall(mytask) but it does not work, logmain parameter remains empty !

Comment: I guess it depends on whether you need the calculation to be performed before you read the result of it.

Comment: You could do `myAnon := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(...); myAnon.FreeOnTerminate := false; myAnon.Start; ... //Do lots of stuff... myAnon.WaitFor; myAnon.Free; // Now you know that the results are calculated`. Note: the calculations results are left in `llog`. You need to copy them to `logMain`.

Comment: You are not passing the var parameter ‘pmainlog’ to the thread in ‘MajorProcessing’ because you are making a copy of that record to the local variable ‘llog’.

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to [How do I pass a context inside a loop into a TTask.IFuture in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706948/how-do-i-pass-a-context-inside-a-loop-into-a-ttask-ifuture-in-delphi)

IFuture is the concurrent function to accompany ITask concurrent procedures.

If we create a function variable that depends on the loop index, then we can bind the value of the index into the function to be used as a Future.

This version creates an array of strings.
The same will work for your TRCLog record.

```
program ProjThreadLogging;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
     System.SysUtils,
     System.Classes,
     System.Threading;

const
     procs = 8;

var
     idxlog     : integer;
     s          : string;
     futurefunc : TFunc<string>;
     logstrs    : array [1..procs] of IFuture<string>;

function CreateIdxLogFunc(idxlog:integer):TFunc<string>;
     begin
       Result := function:string
                 begin
                    {Some calculation that takes time}
                    Sleep(1000*idxlog);
                    Result:='Proc ' + idxlog.ToString;
                 end;
     end;

begin
     for idxlog in [1..procs] do begin
         futurefunc      :=   CreateIdxLogFunc(idxlog);
         logstrs[idxlog] :=   TTask.Future<string>( futurefunc );
     end;

     for idxlog in [1..procs] do begin
         writeln(logstrs[idxlog].Value);
     end;

     Readln;
end.
```