# delphi variable value is changing at thread in a loop

Tags: delphi

my code is running a for loop to process some data like here

```
procedure printValue(Value: Integer);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current, procedure
  begin
   form1.memo1.lines.add( Value.ToString );
  end);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  myThread : TThread;
  Proc1: TMyProc;
begin
  for I := 0 to 10 do
  begin
    myThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      printValue( i );
    end);
    myThread.Start;
  end;
end;
```

this code out put is like this:

```
3
5
6
8
9
11
10
4
11
4
7
```

this is not good so i add a small delay like `sleep(1)` after thread start.this will fix output problem but not a good idea because in a large loop block the ui thread so try to use [this document as help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223428) so my code changed like this:

```
function CaptureValue(Value: Integer): TMyProc;
begin
  Result := procedure begin Writeln(Value); end;
end;

procedure printValue(Value: Integer);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current, procedure
  begin
   form1.memo1.lines.add( Value.ToString );
  end);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  myThread : TThread;
  Proc1: TMyProc;
begin
  for I := 0 to 10 do
  begin

    myThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      Proc1:= CaptureValue(i);
      printValue( Proc1 );
    end);
    myThread.Start;
  end;
end;
```

but i got `[dcc32 Error] Unit11.pas(57): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'` error.

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is wrong is explained in the error message, your PrintValue expects an integer but you're passing a reference to a procedure. Anyway, I don't think your problem is related with variable capture. You simply can't tell the threads when to start/finish.

Comment: ... even the sleep is not guaranteed to work, although it will increase the likelihood of getting your expected result.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yes for this reason i have to avoid sleep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anonymous procedures capture variables, not values. [This is documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi#Variable_Binding_Mechanism). So in both of your examples, your threads are sharing a single `I` variable with no synchronization over the access of that variable.

You had the right idea to pass `I` to a procedure and then capture it from the argument list before using it.  However, you went about it the wrong way.

The reason your second example actually fails to compile is because you are misusing `CaptureValue()`. It returns a `TMyProc`, which is clearly a `reference to procedure` (which BTW, the RTL already has a `TProc` for that same purpose). You are passing an anonymous procedure as-is to `printValue()`, which takes an `Integer` instead. That is what the compiler error is complaining about.

The way you are using the return value, `CaptureValue()` would have to instead return an anonymous function that itself returns an `Integer` (ie, have `CaptureValue()` return a `reference to function: Integer`, aka `TFunc<Integer>`), then *call* that function and pass *that* return value to `PrintValue()`.

You are still capturing `I` itself before passing it to `CaptureValue()`, though, so you still have threads sharing `I`. You would need to call `CaptureValue()` from inside the loop directly before calling `CreateAnonymousThread()`. But then, your threads would be capturing and sharing the `Proc1` variable instead, so you would be right back to the original problem.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```pascal
procedure PrintValue(Value: Integer);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add( Value.ToString );
    end
  );
end;

function CaptureAndPrintValue(Value: Integer): TProc;
begin
  Result := procedure
    begin
      printValue( Value );
    end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to 10 do
  begin
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      CaptureAndPrintValue(I)
    ).Start;
  end;
end;
```

Or, you can let the RTL handle the threading for you:

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.Threading;

procedure PrintValue(Value: Integer);
begin
  // can't use TThread.Synchronize() with TParallel, as it
  // doesn't service the main message queue while looping...
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add( Value.ToString );
    end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TParallel.For(0, 10,
    procedure(I: Integer)
    begin
      PrintValue(I);
    end
  );
end;
```

Comment: thank you but the first code output is : `0 2 3 6 7 10 1 8 4 5 9` the second code is hanged and dont show any output!

Comment: @peimanF. That output is perfectly fine given the threaded nature of your loop. The order of the output numbers is not guaranteed. If you are expecting the numbers to be output in order, then you don't understand how threads work. But you can see that no numbers are being repeated anymore, unlike with your original code. As for the hang, I forgot that `TThread.Synchronize()` doesn't work with `TParallel.For()`.i updated that example to use `TThread.Queue()` instead

Comment: yes, if data doesn't lose is enough for me at this point.but why when a thread start sooner pass value later to memo !?!?

Comment: @peimanF. That is just how threads work. They run in parallel. Just because you start them in order does not mean they will end up syncing back to the UI in the same order. It depends on system timing. The timing between when a thread is created and when it actually starts running. The timing of task switches between threads running on the same CPU. The timing between threads running on different CPUs.

Comment: `The timing of task switches between threads running on the same CPU. The timing between threads running on different CPUs` really understandable.thank you for your useful information..