# delphi tcp server on multi port hanged on close

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

i used a multi port tcp server to receive some connections

like this

```
procedure TForm2.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
    aByte: Byte;
    i,j , tmBodyFrameLength:integer;
    myThread : tthread;
begin
    if not Assigned( allOfflineStringList ) then
    begin
        allOfflineStringList := TStringlist.Create;
    end;
    allOfflineStringList.Clear;

   case AContext.Binding.Port of
      55000: begin       {offline and image}
              AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(data, 1099, False);
              rowFrame :='';
              for I := 0 to length(data)-1 do
              begin
                rowFrame := rowFrame + (data[i].ToHexString);
              end;
              newFrame := copy( rowFrame , 9 , maxInt );
              allOfflineStringList.Append( newFrame );

              TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
              procedure ()
              begin
                  Label985.caption := 'Offline : ' + allOfflineStringList.Count.ToString ;
                  //Memo14.Lines.Add( datetimetostr(now) +':'+ newFrame );
                  form2.AbLED601.Tag := DateTimeToUnix(now);
                  form2.AbLED601.Checked := true;
              end);
      end;

      55001: begin             {tm online}
          repeat
              aByte := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
              if aByte=$C0 then
              begin
                  SDRtmOnlineRowFrame2 := SDRtmOnlineRowFrame;
                  SDRtmOnlineRowFrame := '';
                  TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
                  procedure ()
                  begin
                      form2.Memo14.Lines.Add('tm:'+ SDRtmOnlineRowFrame2 );
                  end);
              end
              else
              begin
                 SDRtmOnlineRowFrame := SDRtmOnlineRowFrame + aByte.ToHexString;
              end;
          until true;
      end;

      55003: begin      {beacon online}
          repeat
              aByte := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
              if aByte=$C0 then
              begin
                  SDRtmOnlineBeaconRowFrame2 := SDRtmOnlineBeaconRowFrame;
                  SDRtmOnlineBeaconRowFrame := '';
                  TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
                  procedure ()
                  begin
                      form2.Memo14.Lines.Add('beacon:'+ SDRtmOnlineBeaconRowFrame2 );
                  end);
              end
              else
              begin
                 SDRtmOnlineBeaconRowFrame := SDRtmOnlineBeaconRowFrame + aByte.ToHexString;
              end;
          until true;
      end;
   end;
 end;
```

every thing working good 
but when data is receiving if i close the connection

app will hange and dont responding any more!

enable and disable is like this:

```
procedure TForm2.CheckBox6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ic:integer;
  allIpList : TStringList;
begin
   AbLED412.Checked := CheckBox6.Checked;

   if CheckBox6.Checked=true then
   begin

      IdTCPServer1.Active := False;
      IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;

      with IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add do
      begin
        //IP := '192.168.1.5';
        Port := 55000;
      end;

      with IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add do
      begin
        //IP := '192.168.1.5';
        Port := 55001;
      end;

      with IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add do
      begin
        //IP := '192.168.1.5';
        Port := 55003;
      end;

      IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
      IdTCPServer1.StartListening;

      TIdStack.IncUsage;
      try
        allIpList := TStringList.Create;
        GStack.AddLocalAddressesToList( allIpList );
        memo14.lines.clear;
        for ic := 0 to allIpList.Count-1 do
        begin
          memo14.lines.Add('Create tcp connection on ip : '+allIpList[ic]+' and port : 55000');
          memo14.lines.Add('Create tcp connection on ip : '+allIpList[ic]+' and port : 55001');
          memo14.lines.Add('Create tcp connection on ip : '+allIpList[ic]+' and port : 55003');
        end;
      finally
        TIdStack.DecUsage;
      end;


   end
   else
   begin
        IdTCPServer1.StopListening;
        IdTCPServer1.Active := False;
        IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;
        memo14.lines.clear;
   end;

end;
```

also when data is receiving if i close the app it hanged again 
but when sender disconnected closing the app dont make any problem

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` handler is using multiple variables in a *thread-unsafe* manner.  You are not protecting them from multiple threads accessing them at the same time, thus causing race conditions on their data.

But, more importantly, your use of `TThread.Synchronize()` is a common cause of deadlock for `TIdTCPServer` because it is a multi-threaded component.  Its `OnConnect`, `OnDisconnect`, `OnExecute`, and `OnError` events are called in the context of client worker threads, not in the main UI thread. `TThread.Synchronize()` blocks the calling thread until the main UI thread processes the request.  Deactivating `TIdTCPServer` terminates all running client threads and waits for them to fully terminate.  So, if you call `TThread.Synchronize()` in a client thread *while* the main UI thread is blocked deactivating the server, then the client thread is waiting on the main UI thread while the main UI thread is waiting on the client thread - deadlock!

You have a few options to solve this:

- avoid calling `TThread.Synchronize()` while deactivating the server. Easier said than done though, as you might already be in a pending `TThread.Synchronize()` by the time you decide to deactivate `TIdTCPServer`. And it is a race condition when making the decision whether to call `TThread.Synchronize()` or not.
- deactivate `TIdTCPServer` in a separate worker thread, leave the main UI thread free to process `TThread.Synchronize()` and `TThread.Queue()` requests.  If you use a `TThread` for the deactivation, calling the `TThread.WaitFor()` method in the main UI thread will process `Synchronize()`/`Queue()` requests while it is waiting for the thread to terminate.
- Use `TThread.Queue()` instead of `TThread.Synchronize()`, especially when performing actions that your client threads don't actually need to wait on, such as UI updates.

---

On a side note, in your `CheckBox6Click()`:

- you should not be calling `TIdTCPServer.StartListening()` or `TIdTCPServer.StopListening()` at all.  The `TIdTCPServer.Active` property setter calls them internally for you.
- you don't need to call `TIdStack.IncUsage()` or `TIdStack.DecUsage()` either, as `TIdTCPServer`'s constructor and destructor call them for you.
- you are leaking `allIpList` as you don't `Free()` it. And `TIdStack.AddLocalAddressesToList()` is deprecated anyway, you should be using `TIdStack.GetLocalAddressList()` instead.

Try this:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.CheckBox6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ic: integer;
  allIpList : TIdStackLocalAddressList;
begin
  AbLED412.Checked := CheckBox6.Checked;

  if CheckBox6.Checked then
  begin
    IdTCPServer1.Active := False;
    IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;

    with IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add do
    begin
      //IP := '192.168.1.5';
      Port := 55000;
    end;

    with IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add do
    begin
      //IP := '192.168.1.5';
      Port := 55001;
    end;

    with IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add do
    begin
      //IP := '192.168.1.5';
      Port := 55003;
    end;

    IdTCPServer1.Active := True;

    allIpList := TIdStackLocalAddressList.Create;
    try
      GStack.GetLocalAddressesList( allIpList );
      Memo14.Lines.Clear;
      {
      for ic := 0 to IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Count-1 do
      begin
        Memo14.Lines.Add('Create tcp connection on ip : ' + IdTCPServer1.Bindings[ic].IP + ' and port : ' + IntToStr(IdTCPServer1.Bindings[ic].Port));
      end;
      }
      for ic := 0 to allIpList.Count-1 do
      begin
        if allIpList[ic].IPVersion = ID_DEFAULT_IP_VERSION then
        begin
          Memo14.Lines.Add('Create tcp connection on ip : ' + allIpList[ic].IPAddress + ' and port : 55000');
          Memo14.Lines.Add('Create tcp connection on ip : ' + allIpList[ic].IPAddress + ' and port : 55001');
          Memo14.Lines.Add('Create tcp connection on ip : ' + allIpList[ic].IPAddress + ' and port : 55003');
        end;
      end;
    finally
      allIpList.Free;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    IdTCPServer1.Active := False;
    IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;
    Memo14.Lines.Clear;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you ,i just need to update main ui thread so its better if i use `TThread.Queue` but if i use `TThread.Queue` instead of `TThread.Synchronize` there inst risk of face the `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516133` problem!? if there was a delay i execute the `form2.Memo14.Lines.Add` the variable `SDRtmOnlineRowFrame2` get a new value ?!

Comment: @peimanF. "*if i use `TThread.Queue` instead of `TThread.Synchronize` there inst risk of face the `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516133` problem!?*" - yes, so you would have to code for that properly. Plenty of examples floating around. *"if there was a delay i execute the `form2.Memo14.Lines.Add` the variable `SDRtmOnlineRowFrame2` get a new value ?!*" - the code you showed already suffers from that problem anyway, because `SDRtmOnlineRowFrame2` is one of the (several) variables you are sharing across threads without protecting it from concurrent access.